# What notation is used to show that a variable is a matrix?

Tags: matrices, nomenclature, vector

When a variable is a vector, it is common to put an arrow above the variable, shown bellow

```
\vec{x}
```

When a variable is a matrix, sometimes a capital letter is used to distinguish it from the ordinary vectors and scalars.

But what should I do if I cant use a capital letter? I have a variable Omega that sometimes is a vector and sometimes is a matrix. It always is capital Omega to show it represents a solid angle. I need to distinguish the vector Omega from the matrix Omega. How could I do this?

Comment: Some times I see bold face: `\mathbf{A}`. Or brackets `[\Omega]`.

Comment: Some use brackets around the variable.

Comment: In German math lectures often an underlined character is used.

Comment: There is basically no general rule, anyway, you should clearify your symbol style at the beginning of your document

Comment: `Let $\Omega$ be a $m\times m$ matrix`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more about notational conventions than about TeX. Should perhaps be migrated to one of the maths sites.

Comment: @Jubobs I was worried it might be. I thought because of the nomenclature tag that these questions were okay here. If not I would be happy for it to be migrated to a maths site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DIN EN ISO 80000-2:2013-08 recommends to use bold, italic capital letters.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\myMatrix}[1]{\bm{\mathit{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\myMatrix{\Omega} \ne \myMatrix{A}
\]
\[
\myMatrix{\Omega} = \begin{pmatrix}
\omega_{11} & \cdots & \omega_{1j} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\omega_{i1} & \cdots & \omega_{ij}
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\[
\omega_{ij} \coloneqq (\myMatrix{\Omega})_{ij}
\]
Alternatively you may write:
$
\myMatrix{\Omega} \coloneqq (\omega_{ij})
$
or
$
\omega_{ij} \coloneqq \left[\myMatrix{\Omega}\right]_{ij}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

For vectors, I would recommend the use of bold small letters. As you have to use a capitalized `\Omega`, you should use the arrow notation (default of `\vec{\Omega}`) here.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\let\oldvec\vec
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\oldvec{\mathit{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\vec{\Omega}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: erhm, use the `bm` package, and you do not need that `\boldsymbol` + `\mathit` hack

Comment: @daleif I would say, you are right for most cases, but it will not set the Greek letters in italic.

Comment: It would still call it a hack, plus most people do not use italic greek letters (mostly only those trying to strictly follow some iso standard)

Comment: @daleif hehe, I feel addressed! You are right. But as this answer is about the ISO recommendation, I will leave it in. Added the vector version as well.

Comment: this standard should be destroyed. They had too much free time and made up weird stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty solution: Use logical markup

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% Change to another style
\newcommand{\MatrixVariable}[1]{\ensuremath{\underline{#1}}}%


\begin{document}
\MatrixVariable{A}
\MatrixVariable{\Omega}

\end{document}
```

[image]